# Finding the image boundary

Tags: r, image-processing

While I use R quite a bit, just started an image analysis project and I am using the `EBImage` package.  I need to collect a lot of data from circular/elliptical images.  The built-in function `computeFeatures` gives the maximum and minimum radius. But I need all of the radii it computes.

Here is the code.  I have read the image, thresholded and filled.

```
actual.image = readImage("xxxx")
image = actual.image[,2070:4000]
image1 = thresh(image)
image1 = fillHull(image1)
```

As there are several objects in the image, I used the following to label

```
  image1 = bwlabel(image1)
```

I generated features using the built in function

```
  features = data.frame(computeFeatures(image1,image))
```

Now, `computeFeatures` gives max radius and min radius.  I need all the radii of all the objects it has computed for my analysis.  At least if I get the coordinates of boundaries of all objects, I can compute the radii through some other code.

I know images are stored as matrices and can come up with a convoluted way to find the boundaries and then compute radii.  But, was wondering if there a more elegant method?

Comment: Don't you just want the `s.radius.mean` value for each feature?

Comment: No.  I do not want mean.  I want all the values they computed to compute the mean.  Now, for each object I can get min, max and mean.  But, internally, they must be computing 100 or 1000 radii from which they are computing this mean, min and max.  What I want is all the radii of all that they used to compute min, max and mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could try extracting each object + some padding, and plotting the x and y axis intensity profiles for each object. The intensity profiles is simply the sum of rows / columns which can be computed using `rowSums` and `colSums` in R

Then you could find where it dropps by splitting each intensity profiles in half and computing the nearest minimum value.

Maybe an example would help clear things up:
[image]

Hopefully this makes sense